# Make struts1 application independent from struts

Tags: struts-1

I'm a newbie to struts1 and I was wondering if an application built on struts1 can be changed some how to make it independent of struts. If at all i want to change, what are the changes that I'll need to perform?

I know that I have to convert the struts tags to html tags. Is this the only change that i need to perform or there are more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by using the JSTL instead of most of the logic and bean tags. Other than that, your application will be dependant on Struts, and there's no way around it, other than

- not using any of what the framework offers, but then why use Struts in the first place
- build some kind of super framework which use Struts behind the scene, but could be migrated to another underlying MVC framework. But you'll probably lose more time creating and migrating the framework than it takes to build the whole app using Struts and migrate the app to another framework.

Struts1 is obsolete anyway, and shouldn't be used for new projects. Prefer more modern frameworks such as Stripes or Spring MVC.

Comment: I'm at a situation where I have to implement the struts hello world example without using the struts framework and the example is given in the following link [http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-hello-world-example-1.html](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-hello-world-example-1.html). Is it possible to implement the struts example with MVC and without struts framework. Are the struts framework and MVC model inseparable for this particular implementation?

Comment: It's of course possible to display a HelloWorld page using the MVC pattern without using Struts. Since the tutorial is about Struts, it will obviously make the application dependant on Struts. You just need a servlet and a JSP to reimplement that without Struts.

Comment: I really appreciate the help my friend. I can handle it from here. I'll use doGet() and doPost().